# Pcretest seems to be gone from libpcre3 package

Tags: 11.04

pcretest in 11.04 seems to be missing from libpcre packages and I can't seem to find where it went off to.  I kind of love using it to test regular expressions. Where did it go?

Answer (score 2):

It was dropped in [version 8.12-3ubuntu1](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/pcre3/pcre3_8.12-3ubuntu2/changelog):

```
pcre3 (8.12-3ubuntu1) natty; urgency=low

  * FFe LP: #733501
  * Drop pcretest from the libpcre3 package, to allow for correct
    coinstallability.
  * Build for multiarch, pre-depending on multiarch-support.

 -- Steve Langasek <steve.langasek@ubuntu.com>  Thu, 17 Mar 2011 11:05:43 -0700
```

The relevant commit can be found [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/natty/pcre3/natty/revision/29).

The file is still available in [Maverick](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/amd64/libpcre3/filelist)'s package.

Other than using older builds (discouraged) or building it from source, I suggest you to fill [a bug against the `pcre3` source package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/pcre3).